# how to append an array into list

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, list, numpy

I have a problem to append my array that created from numpy library. Here is my python's code

```
# to get array's column name
columnData = [x[0] for x in curHeader.description]
# to get data result
rData = curHeader.fetchall()
# loop data
for i in rData:
    arrayData = np.asarray(dict(zip(columnData, i)))

# print data
print(arrayData)
# {'KD_VAL': 'USD', 'FOB': None, 'FREIGHT': None, 'CIF': 33090.0}

# sample append data into list
listData.append(arrayData)

# Convert listData to json
# Insert json into MongoDB using insert_many
```

Unfortunately, the array can't insert into my mongoDB event my code doesn't produce an error. Is there any logical missing?

Thanks!

Comment: did you tried extend instead of append?

Comment: what is listData? Can you share similar print(listData) like print(arrayData)

Comment: @SanthoshKumar, I have tried that, but doesn't clear the issue

listData is a list that I used to combine data before create json.
Here's the sample format
[
   "name": "nanang",
   "data": {
            "kd_val": "USD",
            "fob": None
    }
]

Comment: please share listData value

Comment: done [ "name": "nanang", "data": { "kd_val": "USD", "fob": None } ]

Comment: if listData is list, how it is possible to add "key":"value" pair in it? what is the output of type(listData) ?

Comment: I have an answer @SanthoshKumar. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, I have an answer after several trials.

So, the point is only change the code into listData.append(arrayData.toList()).

Thanks to @Santosh Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

if it is possible to skip using numpy arrays this will work

```
array_data = dict(zip(columnData, rData))
list_data.append(array_data)
# my_mongo_collection.insert_many(list_data)
```